# Crear Un Chat en Angular 4 con Socket.Io

Tags: angularjs-2.0, socket.io

He creado un chat en angular 4 con ayuda de socket.io, fino hasta que los mensajes se envian a todo el mundo, necesito que la coneccion sea usuario con usuario, no de todos con todos(por ahora). He leido q use un nickname pero de verdad que no se con q se come eso..

este es mi index.js

```
let express = require('express')
let app = express();

let http = require('http');
let server = http.Server(app);

let socketIO = require('socket.io');
let io = socketIO(server);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('user connected');

    socket.on('new_message', (message) => {
            //socket.emit('new_message',message);
            io.emit('new_message',message);
            console.log( 'el mensaje emitido '+message);
        });

    // socket.on('join-user',(user)=>{

    //  console.log('se unio un usuario'+user);

    // });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`started on port: ${port}`);
});
```

este el servicio>

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export class ChatService {
    private url = 'http://localhost:3000';
    private socket;

    constructor() {
        this.socket = io(this.url);
    }

    public sendMessage(message) {
        this.socket.emit('new_message', message);
    }

    public getMessages = () => { 
        return Observable.create((observer) => {
            console.log('estoy dentro del servicio, dentro del returnn');
            this.socket.on('new_message', (message) => {
                observer.next(message);
            });
        });
    }


    // public getMessages(message){
    //  return this.socket.on('new_message',message);

    // }

}
```

y mi componente :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { RegisterUser,Roles,EditProfile,billetera,Curso} from '../../../model/models';
import { StrService } from '../../../Service/System.service';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { ChatService } from './chart.service';


@Component({
    selector: 'chatsView',
    templateUrl: 'chats.component.html',
    providers :[ChatService],
})

export class ChatsViewComponent implements OnInit {
    public data: any=[];
    message: string;
    messages: string[] = [];
    public username;
  constructor(private chatService: ChatService) {
  }

  sendMessage() {

    this.username = sessionStorage.getItem('user');
    this.chatService.sendMessage(this.message);
    this.message = '';

  }

  ngOnInit() { 
    this.chatService.getMessages().subscribe(message=>{
    console.log('dasd'+ message);
    this.messages.push(message);
    //console.log('ChatComponent Initialized '+this.messages+' y los mensajes');
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solo obtienes el id del socket con el que quieres realizar la conversacion y listo yo lo realizo de este modo desde android no debe ser muy diferente en tu lenguaje

```
io.sockets.connected[id_socket].emit('nuevo mensaje',mensaje);
```

Comment: como saco el id_socket ?? jeje ese es mi duda que id es ese

Comment: solo ocupas poner socket.id(); con eso se obtiene el id del socket conectado puedes poner un console.log para verificar que id tiene

Comment: Y solo con eso tengo el id del socket???? si imprimo console.log(id_socket); sale el id???

Comment: con poner console.log( socket.id() ); debe de mostrarte el id del socket que se conecto al servidor ya es tu decision como manejarlos o donde guardarlos para luego usarlos

Comment: si ya vi q me devuelve un id tipo token,, ahora bien, si el otro usuario quiere conectarse conmigo solamente por ejemplo?? disculpa mi ingnorancia primera vez q toco esto

Comment: no hay problema yo tengo 6 meses usandolo aun no soy experto tampoco pero yo lo que hago es obtener el id de los dos sockets que se quieren comunicar y uso la forma que publique primero poniendo el id respectivo para cada usuario

Comment: exacto esa idea me vino a la mente , tengo pensado por ejemplo pasar ya el id del usuario pues.. por decir un ejemplo q muestre un select con todos los conectados algo asi y yo seleccione uno

Comment: oye disculpa de nuevo.  este ejemplo q puso el amigo arriba (io.sockets.connected[id_socket].emit('nuevo mensaje',mensaje); ) me explota. cual es la manera de enviarlo ??

Comment: prueba con esto 
     `socket.on('nuevo mensaje', function(mensaje){
      try{
        broadcast_nuevo_mensaje('nuevo mensaje',mensaje,socket.id());
      }catch(Exception){
        console.log(Exception);
      }
      
  });` 



y esta seria la funcion broadcas 


`function broadcast_nuevo_mensaje(event, data, id_socket) {
    io.sockets.connected[id_socket].emit(event,data);
}`

Comment: jajajaja wao . intentare ... gracias bro